# How to remove unwanted exe files/programs

Tags: uninstall, malware

How to remove Torntv program from ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [virustotal webpage for Torntv Downloader.exe](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/395db6ee54b0e8a098ee21e4866817fb0e07852b72640099f70f67b427ae3c0d/analysis/), ClamAV antivirus with its antivirus definitions updated to July 6, 2013 or later will detect the Torntv Downloader.exe malware.

ClamTk is a graphic front-end for ClamAV antivirus. In order to install ClamAV, open the Ubuntu Software Center and search for ClamTk or run the following command from the terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get install clamtk
```

The [Ubuntu Documentation ClamAV wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV) contains information about how to use ClamAV. By default the ClamTk GUI front-end displays the names of all infected files, but does not delete them, so you have to delete them manually. If you want to scan for infected files and also delete them automatically, you can do this by running clamav from the terminal according to the instructions in the Ubuntu Documentation ClamAV wiki in the sections of the wiki titled **Scan Files** and **Remove Infected Files**.

Comment: Thanks for the useful ClamAV information. I've installed that, it helped to remove a few threats found. But Torntv is still there,i guess it isn't a threat. Anyway how to uninstall it from the system? It wasn't installed from the software center.

Comment: Torntv is malware, and it is indeed a threat. Its files should searched for and removed from your system. If you find a file that you suspect is malware, you shouldn't delete it immediately. Instead compress the file as a zip archive and delete the original. Then move the zip file into a folder that you made called _Quarantine_ in any one of your user directories (e.g. _Documents_). After waiting for a month or so, you can delete the files in your Quarantine directory after you are sure that you can delete them without causing damage to your system.

Comment: @JelenaKiselova: I have written some additional information about Torntv that is too long to put in a comment, and copied it to Ubuntu Pastebin at [this link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5868245/)

Comment: I think TornTV is removed from the system. It was stored with Wine folders.By going to Wine Uninstall Software and removing it from there the program doesn't respond anymore although the icon still appears in Dash. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

This depends how you have installed your program. If you have installed using your systems package manager, you need to go to the Ubuntu Software Center, search for your program under "Installed" and click on "remove".

If not, then the matter is more complex. It might have been installed in a separate folder (in which case you just have to remove that folder), or it might have its own installer / deinstaller.

Comment: It wasn't installed from the Software center actually. So how to find the location of the folder to remove it?